# Using do_shortcode with variables?

Tags: shortcode

Struggling to get the format right for the PHP in this do_shortcode embed using variables from Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I think I've tried every variation on ., ', and ". After reading every resource I could find I'm still no closer.

```
<?php 
    $address = get_field('cong_streetaddress');
    $city = get_field('cong_city');
    $province = get_field('cong_province');
    $postalcode = get_field('cong_postalcode');

    echo do_shortcode('[pw_map address="'" . $address . " . " . $city . " . " . $province . " . " . $postalcode . "'" width="100%" height="200px"]'); 
?>
```

Doing it with just one variable, like so `echo do_shortcode('[pw_map address="'. $postalcode . '" width="100%" height="200px"]');` works fine.

Comment: Please add the callback function for this shortcode to your question. It will be much easier then to give a useful answer. Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thanks very much for the welcome and for your help. This is quite the resource - I'm amazed. The shortcode is generated by a plugin called simple google maps short code http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-maps-short-code/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is broken, the quote marks do not match. Try to separate data from the shortcode template, and use [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$shortcode = sprintf(
    '[pw_map address="%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s" width="%5$s" height="200px"]',
    $address,
    $city,
    $province,
    $postalcode,
    '100%'
);
echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
```

That’s much easier to read, and it is harder to create syntax errors. :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to return anything (I think because it doesn't have values for any of those variables). I edited like so: `<?php 
   
    $address = get_field('cong_streetaddress');
    $city = get_field('cong_city');
    $province = get_field('cong_province');
    $postalcode = get_field('cong_postalcode');
      
    $shortcode = sprintf(
        '[pw_map address="%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s" width="100%" height="200px"]',
        $address,
        $city,
        $province,
        $postalcode
    );
    echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
    
   ?>` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Oops. How does one format code blocks in comments?

Comment: One does not simply code into Comments

Comment: @JimKite The `%` in `100%` might have mixed up `sprintf()`. Try the changed code now.

Comment: The percentage mark change doesn't seem to have made any difference as far as I can see. It still doesn't return anything to the page. Was I correct to be declaring the variables before this code?

Comment: Maybe the field values are empty or no valid address data? Print them out to see it.

Comment: Doing `print_r ($address);` right before the `echo do_shortcode` showed the address.

Comment: That was my stupidity. Your code worked perfectly. I didn't check the postal code entered in the testing post was correct, and it must have been producing a conflict with the address and thus not returning a map at all. Thanks so much for the help and apologies for the mistake.

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out. :) Click the little checkmark (✔) on the left side, so other readers know that solves the problem.